# Vagrant/Virtualbox/Docker networking

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm working on a windows 11 pc with a wsl2/ubuntu machine.
My pc have an ip of 192.168.0.19

I installed vagrant inside my ubuntu machine.

I installed docker desktop and virtualbox on my pc.

With docker I started a simple nginx container.

```
version: '3.9'

services:

    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8090:80
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Brussels
        volumes:
            - ./data:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
        networks:
            - proxy

networks:
    proxy:
        name: proxy_network
        external: true
```

For vagrant I'm using that `Vagrantfile`

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/jammy64"  # default username/password : vagrant
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true  # disable shared folder
    config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
    config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.250",  bridge: "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller"
    config.vm.hostname = "dev01"

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
        virtualbox.memory = 2048
        virtualbox.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]  # failed to create the raw output file /dev/null (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
        virtualbox.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "off" ]  # slow to start
        virtualbox.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--graphicscontroller", "vmsvga"]
    end

    config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
        trigger.run = {path: "./ssh-key.sh", args: "add"}
    end

    config.trigger.after :destroy do |trigger|
        trigger.run = {path: "./ssh-key.sh", args: "remove"}
    end

end
```

In wsl (outside of the vagrant machine) I can do a `curl localhost:8090` (and I receive the nginx response) but not `curl 192.168.0.19:8090`.  I don't know why.

After a `vagrant up` I can do a `ssh vagrant@192.168.0.250`.  Inside of that machine I can do a `ping 192.168.0.19` but not a `curl 192.168.0.19:8090`.  I can also do a `curl www.google.com`  Why ? And how to resolve that ?

I also tried to create a vm directly from virtualbox ui with the same properties and  .... everything works inside that machine.

I don't understand the origin of the problem.